# Excel Workbooks and VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook that I need to put some VBA code into. Unfortunately, our security policies are to disable macros with notification.

However, when I put the code into the Workbook_Open() event, it isn't triggered when I tell it to enable the content.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the settings, closing Excel, and then opening your workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to sign the macro:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-macro-security-HP003084611.aspx

Comment: I don't know that that's it or not. I can run macros, but there doesn't seem to be a workbook or worksheet event that fires when I choose to enable the macros in the security dialog.

Comment: If the macro security level is Medium, user is prompted to enable or disable unsigned macros. If macro is signed, it will run without prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the visibility of this file from the standpoint of your scenario (code needs to run for users within your company's network, code need to run when file is sent to outside vendors, etc.) but you could create a folder somewhere safe, and add it to Excel's Trust Center". Any folder defined there will allow for macros to run automatically without needing to be signed. BUT - doing this could skirt around the reasons Microsoft set up security in this manner; Namely, to keep potentially malicious code from being executed on a device.

If this vba code just needs to be able to be run for folks 'in the office', then such a setup should be no problem; Just create a folder specifically for this file, and add that single file to Excel's Trust Center. I say create a folder for the file so that the Directory added to the trust center has as narrow a focus on where code can be automatically run.

To add such a folder to the Trust Center, Click on the Orb in the upper left-hand corner and choose ExcelOptions --> Trust Center (in left column) --> Trust Center Settings (in main section) --> Trusted Locations (left column again). Here you will find the list of locations where code will automatically run. Simply click the 'Add New Location' button and browse to your folder to add it. Now place your excel file(s) there. Now when they are opened, the Workbook_Open event should fire immediately.

Hope this helps, 
Nim